# Imagem de fundo, usando css

Tags: html, css

Como que faço para colocar uma imagem de fundo na `div`, usando css?

Tentei utilizando aspas simples porém nada aconteceu:

```
background: url('images/html.jpg');
```

Estou fazendo assim no:

```
#tudo { width: 100%; height: 992px; background: url('images/html.jpg');}
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui: __http://jsfiddle.net/XmTVT/__ - tem a certeza que o ficheiro `images/html.jpg` existe na directoria que indicou?

Comment: Ainda estou querendo entender qual o problema e como foi solucionado se a resposta do usuário abaixo está igual ao código que você apresentou.

Comment: Oi Paulo eu não estava conseguindo linkar o background com html e css, por algum motivo não estava funcionando porém utilizei a opção chamando o stylo dentro da DIV conforme foi informado acima, com isso eu consegui fazer o que desejava. Por isso foi solucionado a minha dúvida. Obrigado a todos.

Comment: @TheMax colocar estilo dentro da div não é uma prática recomendada, o CSS deve estar sempre separado do HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
<div style="background-image:url(images/html.jpg)">Conteúdo da div</div>
```

ou

```
#tudo{
 background-image:url(images/html.jpg);
 width:100%;
 height:992px;
}
<div id="tudo">Conteúdo da div</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado ajudou muito!! Valeu sou novo aqui e vou participar varias vezes!!

Comment: Já que a resposta dele funcionou você deve dá-la como certa clicando na símbolo de correto logo abaixo da pontuação.

Comment: Junior como eu posso da como certa não encontrei o que você falou sobre o símbolo!

Comment: @TheMax Do lado esquerdo << Em baixo da seta ▼

Answer (score 1):

Para isso existem 2 prováveis motivos:

1. A imagem informada (images/html.jpg) não existe
2. Você não incluiu o CSS no arquivo.

A 1° pode ser resolvido acessando a imagem se existir então você não incluiu o CSS no arquivo tente substituir o código do arquivo pelo seguinte:

```
<style>
#tudo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 992px;
  background-image: url(images/html.jpg);
}
</style>
<div id="tudo"></div>
```

Como pode ver através [deste link](http://jsfiddle.net/b38h8/embedded/result/) o código funciona.